# Asynchronously checking a value without bogging down a thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a pattern in my application where I would like to send out some command or start some IO work and wait for it to be completed, or have some mechanism to know if it has completed.

For this I plan to use the `async`/`await` pattern. I assume most people have come to the point in coding where they reach this pattern.

```
while(something)
    DoNothing();
```

Where `DoNothing()` usually ends up eating up some CPU time or just stopping the program altogether. I assume the proper way to get around this is with the `async`/`await` pattern.

In my case I have come up with the following simple method

```
public override async Task<Boolean> PerformProcessingAsync()
{
    StartSomeIOProcessing();
    while (TheIOProcessingResult == null)
        await Task.Yield();
    return true;
}
```

Which starts some IO processing and then waits for the result to be instantiated. In the meantime though it calls `Task.Yield` to return to the calling context which can then continue work and also places a continuation of this method (the next while loop iteration) onto the call stack.

*Is this the correct explanation, is this the correct way to fix the scenario described above?*

**EDIT:** In a more specific situation that I am facing... I also maintain another library that performs IO work, basically reading and writing to `SerialPort` objects. This library works by having a `ConcurrentQueue` of reads or writes that it processes with respect to a specific port. A `Task` "sits at the end" of this queue and consume the work as it goes.

Most reading work simply queries some value, parses it, and fires an event `NewData(double myNewData)` which is listened to by the UI. In the UI a state representation is held of the `SerialPort`s data. In the state representation the `NewData` event is handled which updates the value of whatever it corresponds to.

Writing is done in the same manner but there is no event fired upon completion, the port is simply written to. The only way to tell if it was successful is to wait for the reads to update the state. (Sadly because of how the hardware acts there is no better way to do this).

---

My current application makes use of this library to perform its IO work. Reads are periodically sent to the library to keep the UI with fresh values from the ports... When a user clicks a button writes are sent off to the library to command something from the hardware.

I am in the situation where I want to assure that the write has happened *programmatically*. The only way I can think to do this is to send the write off to the library, and wait for the read to update the data the write effects.

Thus the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106634/discussion-between-scott-chamberlain-and-kdecker).

Comment: I have deleted all my old comments as they where merged in to our chat, you can do the same if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am in the situation where I want to assure that the write has happened programmatically. The only way I can think to do this is to send the write off to the library, and wait for the read to update the data the write effects.

Yes, that likely is the only way to do it, but there are better ways than spin waiting to see if the read update happens.

Here is a example way to handle the processing like we talked in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106634/discussion-between-scott-chamberlain-and-kdecker) we did. In summary, you have a queue of `IDataRequest`, in those request's they hold a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` that represents the completion of sending the data. Once you do a request to the device and get a response you set the result of the completion source. I combined it with your existing event based implmentation, but honestly I would drop the event's and just have the callers do the update to the UI after awaiting the result of `RequestTemp()`.

```
public interface IDataRequest
{
    bool TrySetException(Exception ex);
}

public abstract class DataRequest<T> : IDataRequest
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<T> RequestTask { get; } = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    public bool TrySetException(Exception ex)
    {
        return RequestTask.TrySetException(ex);
    }
}

public class TempRequest : DataRequest<double>
{
}

public class RpmRequest : DataRequest<int>
{
}

public sealed class DeviceManager : IDisposable
{

    private readonly Task _workerThread;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<IDataRequest> _queue;
    private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

    public DeviceManager()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<IDataRequest>();
        _workerThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessQueue, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
        _serialPort = //...
    }
    
    public event EventHandler<double> TempUpdate;
    public event EventHandler<int> RpmUpdate;

    public Task<double> RequestTemp()
    {
        var request = new TempRequest();
        _queue.Add(request);
        return request.RequestTask.Task;
    }

    public Task<int> RequestRpm()
    {
        var request = new RpmRequest();
        _queue.Add(request);
        return request.RequestTask.Task;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        _workerThread.Wait();
    }

    private void ProcessQueue()
    {
        foreach (var dataRequest in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            try
            {
                if (dataRequest is TempRequest)
                {
                    DoTempRequest((TempRequest)dataRequest);
                }
                else if (dataRequest is RpmRequest)
                {
                    DoRpmRequest((RpmRequest)dataRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"A Request of type {dataRequest.GetType()} is not supported.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dataRequest.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoTempRequest(TempRequest dataRequest)
    {
        _serialPort.WriteLine("Temp ?");
        var line = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        double result;

        //I am deliberately using Parse instead of TryParse so responses that 
        //fail to parse will throw and get their exception propagated up via the 
        //catch in ProcessQueue().
        result = double.Parse(line);
        
        //Sends the info back to the caller saying it is done and what the result was.
        dataRequest.RequestTask.TrySetResult(result);

        //Raises the event so subscribers know the new value.
        OnTempUpdate(result);
    }

    private void DoRpmRequest(RpmRequest dataRequest)
    {
        _serialPort.WriteLine("RPM ?");
        var line = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        int result;
        result = int.Parse(line);
        
        dataRequest.RequestTask.TrySetResult(result);
        OnRpmUpdate(result);
        
    }

    private void OnTempUpdate(double result)
    {
        TempUpdate?.Invoke(this, result);
    }

    private void OnRpmUpdate(int result)
    {
        RpmUpdate?.Invoke(this, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the `StartSomethingIOProcessing` into a separate `Task` that returns the result. `Await` on that, then check the result.

```
public async PerformProcessingAsync()
{
    var ioProcessingResult = await StartSomeIOProcessing();
    return (null != ioProcessingResult);
}

private Task<TheIOProcessingResultType> StartSomeIOProcessing()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
    {
        return StartSomeIOProcessing();
    });
}
```

Comment: Think of `StartSomeIOProcessing`  as `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` With a worker that does `{ Thread.Sleep(5000); TheIOProcessingResult  = Foo(); }`. How would your code ever see the assignment of `Foo`?

Comment: StartSomeIOProcessing will need to return Foo(), instead of assigning the value inside.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are misinterpreting the async/await operations. The await keyword is actually used to wait until the async operation finished so you don't need to implement a while loop anymore and check if it is null.

```
public override async Task<Boolean> PerformProcessingAsync()
{
    await Task.Run((() =>
    {
            StartSomeIOProcessing();
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `StartSomeIOProcessing` is a blocking call, so your code would start the work and immdeatly return saying it was done.

Comment: But this would never check to make sure that `TheIOProcessingResult` is not null?

Comment: Anything that is inside the Task.Run will be executed in a separate thread. So it doesn't matter if it is a blocking or non-blocking call. As long as you put the await keyword, the UI thread will wait for the task to finish first.

Comment: In this case you can implement your check after the awaited Task. You don't need to have the while loop anymore.

Comment: @Jay The problem is, the task finishes before the result is ready.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If StartSomeIOProcessing is assigning some values to TheIOProcessingResult, the await will make sure that the result is always ready after the Task is finished. If TheIOProcessingResult is still null after the Task has finished then there's something wrong with StartSomeIOProcessing method.

Comment: Think of `StartSomeIOProcessing`  as `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` With a worker that does `{ Thread.Sleep(5000); TheIOProcessingResult  = Foo(); }`. How would your code ever see the assignment of `Foo`? It is not going to wait the 5 seconds, because `RunWorkerAsync()` returns instantly.

Comment: In my understanding, his problem is he wants to wait for something to finish before doing something. That is why he has the pseudocode while (something) DoNothing. And Async/Await and BackgroundWorker implementation is completely different. If you want to know if the task is still running then you need to introduce IProgress for the Task to consume and report that it is still busy. The boolean he is returning is only trying to return the caller than the result is already available. It has nothing to do about IsBusy

Comment: Please refresh, I re-worded my example while you where typing to make it more clear, it nolonger contains IsBusy

Comment: Please understand the Async/Await pattern better. The await keyword is there to wait for the 5 seconds to finish before returning.

Comment: You should try it out and you'll understand.