# Use async/ await or something else

Tags: c#, asynchronous, serial-port, async-await

I'm writing a program that communicates with some control hardware that I've designed. The hardware is driving motors and the first thing I'm trying to do with it is to initialize a motor.
The hardware is comm controlled, so to do anything I simply send a message out through USB to the hardware.
To initialize a motor I have to send 2 messages; after I send the first one it moves the motor toward a sensor, and when it reaaches it it stops and sends a message back to me telling me that it has stopped, at which point I send it another message telling it to drive the motor in the opposite direction very slowly until it comes out of the sensor.

All of my comms reception is in a `SerialPort` `DataReceived` event. What is the best way that I can wait for the relevant message and then send the second message? At the moment I'm simply using a property of type bool which I set to true just before initialization, and then in my event handler if I receive the message telling me that the motor has stopped and the bool is true, I set the bool to false and send the second message. While this works I was thinking that it might be possible to use async and await? And that this might be a little more efficient in general? Or is there another approach that I could take that would be better?
Any feedback/ guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not close enough to be called a duplicate, but you may want to look at the design I came up [for a similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066568/asynchronously-checking-a-value-without-bogging-down-a-thread/36070635#36070635) for a class that queue's requests to a SeralPort and waits for a response asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for that, very useful! I'll see if I can adapt and implement something similar but I cannot use the exact answer that you proposed as I really do need the event to handle the reception of messages.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the nice thing about async-await is not that it keeps your caller responsive, but your code looks easier, almost as if it was not async-await.

Keeping your caller responsive can also be accomplished using Tasks and ContinueWith statements, or by using a Backgroundworker or other methods to create a thread. But if you use async await, you don't have to remember the state of your progress, something you do now by setting the boolean.

Your code would look like this:

```
public Task InitializeAsync(...)
{
    await Send1stMessageAsync();
    await Send2ndMessageAsync();
}
```

[In this article Eric Lippert explained async-await using a kitchen metaphor](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). What happens is that your thread will do everything to send the 1st message until it can't do anything anymore but wait for the reply. Control is then given to the first caller who is not awaiting. That would have been you if you weren't awaiting, for instance if you had the following code:

```
public Task InitializeAsync(...)
{
    var task1stMessage = Send1stMessageAsync();
    // this thread will do everything inside Send1stMessageAsync until it sees an await.
    // it then returns control to this function until there is an await here:
    DoSomeThingElse();
    // after a while you don't have anything else to do, 
    // so you wait until your first messages has been sent
    // and the reply received:
    await task1stMessage;
    // control is given back to your caller who might have something
    // useful to do  until he awaits and control is given to his caller etc.
    // when the await inside Send1stMessageAync is completed, the next statements inside
    // Send1stMessageAsync are executed until the next await, or until the function completes.

    var task2ndMessage = Send2ndMessageAsync();
    DoSomethingUseful();
    await task2ndMessage;
}
```

You wrote that you use events to notify your thread that the data has been received. Although it is not difficult to make your Send1stMessageAsync an async function, you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Consider using a nuget package like [SerialPortStream](https://github.com/jcurl/serialportstream) to get async functions that send messages and wait for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I you are waiting for something to happed and you don't have event handler at your disposal it would be a good idea to use async/await pattern

```
async Task WaitForCompletion()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        while(!theBoolVar)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
}
```

and then just in your code use

```
await WaitForCompletion();
```